# How to get only the date from datetimefield grouped by date

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, python-datetime

Struggeling for many hours now and don't know what do do.

I have a database table with some stuff like below:

```
id  date_time           uuid_id                             status_id   room_label_id   
1   2022-06-06 11:15:00 228451edc3fa499bb30919bf57b4cc32    0           1
2   2022-06-06 12:00:00 50e587d65f8449f88b49129143378922    0           1
3   2022-06-06 12:45:00 d1323b0ebd65425380a79c359a190ec6    0           1
4   2022-06-06 13:30:00 219af9da06ac4f459df2b0dc026fd269    0           1
```

With many more entries. date_time is a datetimefield.
I want to display several columns from this table in a html, grouped by date_time. But firstly i want to display the date out of the datetimefield grouped by date.

With:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
    </tr>

{% for terms in term %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ terms.date_time.date }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

and my view:

```
def schedule(request):
        term = appointment.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'scheduler/schedule.html', {'term' : term})
```

I get as result:

```
Field 1
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
6. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
8. Juni 2022
8. Juni 2022
8. Juni 2022
8. Juni 2022
```

So far, so good. But i need only the date from the datetimefield like the following:

```
Field 1
6. Juni 2022
7. Juni 2022
8. Juni 2022
```

and so on.

Any hints/tips or solutions for that kind of problem?

I also tried to set this up in querys and template language of django but without any luck.

EDIT:

Found a solution on my own. Not the prettiest way, but it works:
In short: displays the date of date_time only if there is a new content to display

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
    </tr>

{% for terms in term %}
    <tr>
        <td>{% ifchanged terms.date_time.date %}
        {{ terms.date_time.date }} {% endifchanged %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you could use one of two possible alternatives.
If you just want the distinct dates from your model instances you could use the following

```
from django.db.models.functions.datetime import TruncDay

days = (appointment
        .objects
        .annotate(day=TruncDay('date_time')
        .order_by('day')
        .values_list('day')
        .distinct())
```

This will give you the list of the distinct days only.

---

As and alternative if you would like to group your data by this day within a template you could use the following

**in your view**

```
from django.db.models.functions.datetime import TruncDay

data_with_days = (appointment
                 .objects
                 .annotate(day=TruncDay('date_time'))
```

and in your template

```
{% regroup data_with_days by day as grouped %}

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for g in grouped %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ g.grouper }}</td>
      <td>
        {% for item in g.list %}
          {{ item }} <!-- Display what you want from your appointment -->
          {% if not forloop.last %}<br/>{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But I changed the way to display my variables into template tags by using views instead of sorting and filtering the datas with template tags. 
So i create a variable in the corrosponding view and give it as a context to the template which show the datas.